# Oxyplot xamarin forms pinch zoom and panning not working for Linear series

Tags: xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am trying to implement zoom and panning in oxyplot Linear series but it does not recognise the zoom or panning. 
I am using IsZoomEnabled = true, IsPanEnabled = true in both the axis.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old [issue](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/issues/62) that has not yet been resolved.

Update: I found another [issue link](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1398) and tested work of OxyPlot.Core 1.0.0 with Xamarin.Forms project. And zoom works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question if this can help anyone who is looking for a solution.

I have removed OxyPlot.Core 2.0 and only used OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms nuget package across PCL, Android, and IOS .
This solved the zoom and panning issue that I have been facing in OxyPlot.Core package.