# Xamarin OxyPlot 1.0.0 pan and zoom not responding on Android Release

Tags: android, xamarin, linker, oxyplot

I'm using OxyPlot 1.0.0 (installed via `NuGet`) to display some linear graphs.

1.0.0 is used because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61436606/oxyplot-xamarin-forms-pinch-zoom-and-panning-not-working-for-linear-series) issue. Pan and zoom do not respond on 2.0.0 and 2.1.0.

I have an open issue [here](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/issues/146#issuecomment-1572085999), but there seems to be very little response from the maintainers of the package to resolve it on the newer versions, and obviously no desire to address issues for 1.0.0.

The graph is displayed correctly, but unfortunately pan and zoom do not respond on Android Release.

pan and zoom work great on:

- Android debug
- iOS debug
- iOS release

I believe this has something to do with the linker, since I've had issues with it before.

My project's linker option for Android are `Sdk Assemblies Only`.

I believe the linker is throwing `PlotController` or some other classes from `OxyPlot` away, and I am unable to figure the correct way to force it to include it.

What I've tried so far:

- `Skip linking assemblies: OxyPlot;OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms`
- On `MainActivity.cs`: `var _ = new OxyPlot.PlotController();`
- In the PlotView View: `PlotView.Controller = new OxyPlot.PlotController();`

Has anyone encountered this issue? Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Does it work with Link None? If so, maybe there is some class in Xamarin that OxyPlot depends on via Reflection, so it gets dropped. But I don't know how you'd find what it is.